# How to call another overloading Function using Aspect or Code Generator in .net

Tags: c#, .net, aspect

I have a question about Aspect or Code Generator.

```
public class Test
{
    public void StartMethod(string str)
    {
        ...
    }
    
    public void StartMethod(string str, object obj)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have some code like upon.
When I call StartMethod("test"), I want to call StartMethod("test", some object);

like this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var test = new Test();
    test.StartMethod("test");
}
```

Actually, Run Code like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var test = new Test();
    test.StartMethod("test", this);
}
```

I think I have to use Aspect because change code in IL.
but I can't find answer in PostSharp etc...

How to call another overloading Function?

I tried using PostSharp, Code generator etc...

Comment: What do you think `this` in a `static` method refers to and how would a tool be able to help you with it?